# PHP curl download image when sent chunked

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping, wget

For downloading image I use this script:

```
<?php
    function download_image($url, $save_to) {
        if(file_exists($save_to))
            unlink($save_to);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 

        $fp = fopen($save_to, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $result);
        fclose($fp);

        chmod($save_to, 0777);
    }

    $url = "http://flo.cubecdn.net/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/400x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/0/4050266152131_1.jpg";
    download_image($url, "download.jpg");
?>
```

When script finishes downloading, it saves file as download.jpg. But it is not jpeg file. What can be the problem?

**EDIT** output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 195.244.32.93...
* Connected to flo.cubecdn.net (195.244.32.93) port 80 (#0)
> GET /media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/400x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/0/4050266152131_1.jpg HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1
Host: flo.cubecdn.net
Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server CCAcc (0.9.1/izm-s11) is not blacklisted
< Server: CCAcc (0.9.1/izm-s11)
< Date: Mon, 24 Nov 2014 10:03:35 GMT
< Content-Type: image/jpeg
< **Transfer-Encoding: chunked**
< Connection: keep-alive
< Last-Modified: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 05:47:03 GMT
< ETag: "546add57-50be"
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Age: 0
< Expires: Wed, 24 Dec 2014 10:03:35 GMT
< X-US: HIT
< Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
< 
* Connection #0 to host flo.cubecdn.net left intact
```

**EDIT 2:**
I think the problem is when server sends image:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Because I can not get image even with **wget**

Comment: change another image url, it will works fine.

Comment: Check contents of your jpg with a text editor. Display any output from curl_error.

Comment: @ToBe I have written output

Comment: @Cattla I know that. I want to know why it does not work for this URL

Comment: @torayeff the output seems to only contain your headers. What's inside your jpg file?

Comment: @ToBe When I try to open image with image viewer: Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x1f 0x8b)

Comment: You should open it with a text editor. Reasoning is, that it does not contain your image data but some textual server response, probably telling you of some error.

Comment: @ToBe I guess the problem is server sends chunked data